# Get indexPath.row in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to get the indexPath.row in cell when I click on my button:

```
@IBAction func cellPlayButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let cell = (sender as AnyObject).superview??.superview as? UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = runnerTableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
    print(indexPath)
}
```

I have this error when I push my button:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have try everything found on Stack Overflow and nothing is working.

Let me know where is the bug! Thanks :)

Comment: `let indexPath = runnerTableView.indexPath(for: cell ?? UITableViewCell())`, which _logically_ does not help on you, but _technically_, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just copy the given extension

```
extension UITableView {    
func indexPath(forItem: AnyObject) -> IndexPath? {
    let itemPosition: CGPoint = forItem.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self)
    return self.indexPathForRow(at: itemPosition)
}}
```

USE:

```
@IBAction func cellPlayButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let indexPath = runnerTableView.indexPath(forItem: sender) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this error when I Click on my cellPlayButtonPressed == Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem convertPoint:toCoordinateSpace:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf6ac11fb0'

Comment: `cellPlayButtonPressed` is the target of UIButton or UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: It's the target of my UIBarButtonItem but I can change it for a simple button, it's not very important I don't really need this toolbar

Comment: yes change it to UIButton will work fine, always works for me

Comment: Yes, Welcome dear (y)

Comment: Why is `forItem` declared as `AnyObject` instead of `UIView`?

Comment: Yes, 'UIView' also can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
@IBAction func cellPlayButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: button.center)
    print(indexPath)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created demo and tested for same its working as aspect. You can use as below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        let fruitName = fruits[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruitName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Delicious!"
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: fruitName)

        //Button added for click event
        let btn = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30))
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        btn.setTitle("Click Here", for: UIControlState.normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickMe), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.addSubview(btn)

        return cell
    }

    func clickMe(sender : UIButton){

        let indexpath : NSIndexPath =  self.indexPathForCellContainingView(view: sender, inTableView: self.tableView)
        print("Current IndexPath Row : \(indexpath.row) Column : \(indexpath.section)")

    }

     func indexPathForCellContainingView(view: UIView, inTableView tableView: UITableView) -> NSIndexPath {
        let viewCenterRelativeToTableview = tableView.convert(CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY), from: view)
        let cellIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: viewCenterRelativeToTableview)!
        return cellIndexPath as NSIndexPath
    }
```

Comment: You can place above function in Shared class or global class to use globally

Comment: I have shared sample code here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByFeqNcDauYZRXZqdkxCWWlBZXc

Answer (score -2):

When you set up your cell in `cellForRow` set the `tag` property of your button to the `indexPath.row` of the cell. Then change your method signature to the following:

```
@IBAction func cellPlayButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // sender.tag == indexPath.row
}
```

If your button is a class other than `UIButton` you can replace that with whatever your class is.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Most `UIView` subclasses like `UIButton` have a `tag` property which is just and integer. You can use this to store the row number that the button is attached to. By changing your pressed method to use the `UIButton` as the sender you can access the `sender.tag` to know which cell row was pressed.

Answer (score -4):

You can send the indexPath for your cell when your are in cellForRowAtIndexPath. And then you have access to the indexPath.

```
func cellForRowAtIndex(_ tableView: UITableView, _ indexPath:IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let UITableViewCell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: UITableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
cell.indexPath = indexPath
return cell
```

}

```
@IBAction func cellPlayButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```